# Make edits to the original csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have three different columns in my csv file, with their respected values. Column B (Name column) in csv file has the values in all caps. I am trying to convert it into first letter caps but when I run the code it returns all the columns squished together and in quotes.

```
The Original File:

Company        Name                 Job Title
xxxxxx        JACK NICHOLSON        Manager
yyyyyy        BRAD PITT             Accountant

I am trying to do:

Company        Name                 Job Title
xxxxxx        Jack Nicholson        Manager
yyyyyy        Brad Pitt             Accountant
```

My code:

```
import csv


with open('C:\\Users\\Data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    data = list(reader)

for item in data:
    if len(item) > 1:
        item[1] = item[1].title()

with open('C:\\Users\\Data.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

My result after I run the code is: Instead of returning three different columns and the second column adjusted with the title() syntax, it returns all the three columns squished together in just one column with quotes.

```
ï»¿"Company","Name","Job Title"
xxxxxx,"JACK NICHOLSON","Manager"
yyyyyy,"BRAD PITT","Accountant"
```

I do not know what is wrong with my snippet. The result has absurd markings in the beginning

Comment: are you sure your csv file doen't have any leading characters? Also, its possible that your file doesn't actually have tabs as the delimiters

Comment: The original csv file only has one tab.

Comment: You should be editing `item[0]` not `item[1]`

Comment: Is the second column in the csv file, Name column that is why it is item[1].

Comment: No it isn't. `item` is a list containing a whole row as a string. You can do `print(type(item))` to see for yourself. Accessing `item[1]` will raise an out of bounds error once you remove `if len(item) > 1:` above it. Thus, `item[0]` will refer to the whole row in string which you want to edit.

Answer (score 1):

A slight change to Mohammed's solution using read_fwf to simplify reading the file.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('old_csv_file')
df.Name = df.Name.str.title()
df.to_csv('new_csv_file', index=False, sep='\t')
```

**EDIT:**
Changed to use a string method over lambda.  I prefer to use lambdas as a last result.

Comment: Even though Name is the column in my csv file, it throws out an error. Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\update.py", line 24, in <module>
       df.Address = df.Address.apply(lambda x: x.title())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line   2744, in __getattr__
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Name'

Comment: can you post the results of df.columns?  ```df.Name``` is trying to access the Name column.  If your column is not named correctly you will have to modify that line of code to match your column names.  I did create a dummy text file, pasted your "Original File" into it, and ran this code and it worked.  I suspect that it may be the format of your actual "Original File"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('old_csv_file', sep='\s{3,}')
df.Name = df.Name.apply(lambda x: x.title())
df.to_csv('new_csv_file', index=False, sep='\t')
```

string.title() converts the string to title case, i.e every first letter of the word in string is capitalized and subsequent letters are converted to lower case.

With df.apply you can perform some operation on an entire column or row.

'\s{3,}' is a regular expression
\s is a space character. \s{3,} is for more than 3 spaces.

When you are reading a CSV format you have to specify how your columns are separated.
Generally columns are separated by comma or tab. But in your case you have  like 5,6 spaces between each column of a row.
So by using \s{3,} I am telling the CSV processor that the columns in a row are delimited by more than 3 spaces.

If I had use only \s then it would have treated First Name and Last Name as two separate columns because they have 1 space in between. So by 3+ spaces I made First Name and Last Name as a single column.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to save the edits into the same, old file?

Comment: Yes. you can use same file for old and new.

Comment: Thanks, if you do not mind can you explain what the '\s{3,}' does?

Answer (score 0):

Take note that `data` stores each row as `list` containing one string only.

Having a length of 1, the statement inside this `if` block won't execute.

```
if len(item) > 1:
    item[1] = item[1].title()
```

Aside from that, reading and writing in binary format is unnecessary.

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\Data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    data = list(reader)

for item in data[1:]:                          # excludes headers
    item[0] = item[0].title()                  # will capitalize the Company column too
    item[0] = item[0][0].lower() + item[0][1:] # that's why we need to revert

    print(item) 
    # see that data contains lists having one element only
    # the line above will output to
    #    ['Company        Name                 Job Title']
    #    ['xxxxxx        Jack Nicholson        Manager']
    #    ['yyyyyy        Brad Pitt             Accountant']


with open('C:\\Users\\Data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(data)
```